# display: -ms-flexbox !important > crash internet explorer 10 on print preview

Tags: css, printing, crash, flexbox, internet-explorer-10

I have one big trouble with ms-flexbox and print:

```
.main_block_class_name
  div
    display: block !important // 1 2
.parent_for_flex_box_classname
  display: -ms-flexbox !important  // 1 3
```

1. By default all div have display as none (auto hide all at print
   media)
2. Show all div in main block. Main block also include flexbox block
3. Show this block as flexbox. But this construction got crash in MSHTML.dll at preview or print

Any help would be apprecated :(

Comment: Can you make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I would be interested in looking into this.

Comment: Sorry, i think this question could be closed, but... I find another issue this is svg in flex box block cause crash, or think so..

Comment: Interesting. I would still be interested in researching the crash.

Comment: I find issue, this is place    div.svg-wrapper(position: relative)>svg   container to div(display:-ms-flexbox) did crash. After i change wrapper div position to absolute, all work now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.button-with-svg-graph
  display -ms-flexbox

.svg-wrapper
 position relative // fix: change it to absolute
```

Cause crash in ie10+ when print or print preview.
For fix this issue, we change positioning to absolute